# Explain this algorithm

Tags: python, palindrome

while solving the [Palindrome problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TAPALIN) on codechef I wrote an algorithm, which gave a TLE on test cases more than 10^6. So taking lead from people who had already solved it I wrote the following code in python.

```
################################################
### http://www.codechef.com/problems/TAPALIN ###
################################################
def pow(b,e,m):
    r=1
    while e>0:
        if e%2==1:
            r=(r*b)%m
        e=e>>1
        b=(b*b)%m
    return r
def cal(n,m):
    from math import ceil
    c=280000002
    a=pow(26, int(ceil(n/2)), m)
    if(n%2==0):
        return ((52*(a-1+m)%m)*c)%m
    else:
        return ((52*(((a-1+m)*c)%m))%m+(a*26)%m)%m
c=int(raw_input())
m=1000000007
for z in range(c):
    print cal(int(raw_input()),m)
```

the pow function is the [Right-to-left binary method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). what i do not understand is:

1. where did the value 280000002 came from?
2. why do we need to perform so many mod operations?
3. is this some famous algorithm of which I am unaware about?

Almost every submitted code on codechef makes use of this very algorithm, but I am unable to decipher it's working. any link to the theory would be appreciated.

I am still unable to figure out what is happening in this exactly. **can anyone write a pseudocode for this formula/algo? also help me understand time complexity for this code**. another thing that amazes me is, if I write this code as:

```
################################################
### http://www.codechef.com/problems/TAPALIN ###
################################################
def modular_pow(base, exponent):
    result=1
    while exponent > 0:
        if (exponent%2==1):
            result=(result * base)%1000000007
        exponent=exponent >> 1
        base=(base*base)%1000000007
    return result
c=int(raw_input())
from math import ceil
for z in range(c):
    n=int(raw_input())
    ans=modular_pow(26, int(ceil(n/2)))
    if(n%2==0):
        print ((52*((ans)-1+ 1000000007)%1000000007)*280000002)%1000000007
    else:
        print ((52*((((ans)-1+ 1000000007)*280000002)%1000000007))%1000000007+(ans*26)%1000000007)%1000000007
```

this improves the performance from **0.6secs to 0.4 secs**. though the best code runs in 0.0 seconds. I am so much confused.

Answer (score 1):

The number `280000002` is Modular Multiplicative Inverse of 25 mod `10^9 + 7`, because we know `10^9 + 7` is prime so it's simply calculated using `pow(25, 10^9 + 7 - 2, 10^9 + 7)`. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

And we need to perform so many mod operations because we don't want to work with big numbers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Never seen this algorithm before but walking through it with some of the easier test cases starts to reveal what is happening (BTW, my guess is everyone is using it because it was the top answer on code chef and everyone is just copying it, I don't think you have to assume it's the only way to do it).

To answer your questions:

> where did the value 280000002 came from?

280000002 is the modulo multiplicative inverse of 25 mod 1000000007. This means that the following congruence is true

```
280000002 * 25 === 1 (mod 1000000007)
```

> why do we need to perform so many mod operations?

Probably just to not be dealing with huge numbers along the way. Although there is some extra math in there that seems to me to just be making the numbers bigger than they need to be, see my note at the end about that. Theoretically you could just do one big mod at the end and get the same result but it's possible our tiny CPUs don't like that.

> is this some famous algorithm of which I am unaware about?

Again, I doubt it. This isn't really an algorithm as it is a mashed up math formula.

Speaking of math, there is some stuff in there that is questionable to me. It's been a while since I messed with this stuff but I'm pretty sure that `(52*(a-1+m)%m)` will always be equivalent to `(52*(a-1)%m` since `52m mod m = 0`. Not sure why you would be adding that huge number there, you may see some performance gain if you get rid of that.

Comment: thanks for the info. surely (52*(a-1+m)%m) = (52*(a-1)%m i was so confused between so many operations that it never occurred to me. Though this wasn't a huge boost but was ideally correct as both codes execute in 0.6 seconds.